# How would I validate this java code?

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):");
        operator= userInput.next();
```

I would like it if +,-,* or / is entered, it accepts the value, if something else is entered, it repeats the question. Until one of the four operators is entered it keeps looping.

I have tried:

```
while (!operator.equals("-") ||operator.equals("+") || operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/") )
    {
        System.out.print("Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):");
        userInput.next();
    }
    operator = userInput.next();
```

but it does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is `operator` a `String` or a `double`?  If it's a `String` why are you trying to assign it with `nextDouble()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to negate the entire condition, but the `!` operator operates only on the first operand that it's attached to, because `!` [has a higher precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than `||` (and `&&`).

You can add clarifying parentheses, to indicate that the whole expression needs to be negated.

```
while ( !(operator.equals("-") || operator.equals("+") ||
          operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/") ) )
```

As an alternative, you can also negate each individual check, being careful to switch to "and" operators (not "-" and not "+" and ...)

```
while (!operator.equals("-") && !operator.equals("+") &&
       !operator.equals("*") && !operator.equals("/") )
```

Additionally, inside the `while` loop, assign the result of `next()` to operator so you can check it again, as you had done at the top of the code.

```
    operator = userInput.next();
```

Also, you probably intended the return of the call to `nextDouble()` to be assigned to another variable besides `operator` (a `String`).

Comment: I have updated the code to use the first option.
 System.out.print("Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):");
  operator= userInput.next();
  while (!(operator.equals("-") || operator.equals("+") || operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/") ) )
  {
  System.out.print("Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):");
  userInput.next();
  }

Comment: However, this happens:

Please enter first number:66
Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):d
Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):+
Enter operation to perform (+ OR - OR * OR /):

Comment: You aren't assigning the next input to `operator`.  As I mentioned in my answer above, inside the `while` loop, assign the result of the call to `next()` to `operator`.